# DataDriver error while running the script

Tags: selenium, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I am getting below error while running the script, please help me to solve the issue -

> ERROR ] [ DataDriver ] Error in robot file:   File
> "C:'filepath'.robot", line 0 [ ERROR ] In source file:   File
> "C:'filepath'../TestData/Data.csv", line 0 [ ERROR ] Calling method
> '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: AttributeError: No
> "Test Template" keyword found for first test case.

Comment: Is this file path correct? `C:'filepath'../TestData/Data.csv`

Comment: Yes, the file path given is correct

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. This will help people to understand your problem and you will receive more appropriate answers.

Comment: You have the Test Template in settings section of your robot test file?

Comment: It works fine with Test Template setting.

Answer (score 0):

The below format fixed the issue with the testdata ----------

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DataDriver    ../TestData/data.csv
Test Template   Login scenarios

*** Test Cases ***  
Login to appl  username    password
    
*** Keywords ***

Login scenarios
        [Arguments]   ${username}  ${password}
        pageLogin.Login   ${username}  ${password}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).